# Table Just below a figure

Tags: tables, graphics, floats

I need to place a table just below a figure in a single page. The table is an explanation of figure so it should not move to next page. I am expecting figure and table at the middle of the page. Please help me

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,totalheight=0.6\textheight]{my figure}
\label{fig.1}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Channel No &1&2&3&4&5\\
\hline
Wavelength ($\mu$m) &7.43&11.03&12.02&12.66&14.08\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: insert table in `figure` environment ... provide mwe that we can show you how to do this.

Comment: In LaTeX, one needs to distinguish between two senses or meanings of the term "table". It can mean either a floating environment called `table`, or it can mean a `tabular`-like environment. It sounds like you're using the latter meaning. If so, just include the explanatory material (in tabular form) inside the `figure` environment.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the "explanatory table" should have its own, separate `\caption`, you needn't do anything special. Just include the `tabular` material inside the `figure` environment. More specifically, (a) start the `figure` environment, (b) insert the graph (via an `\includegraphics` or similar statement), (c) insert a `tabular`-like environment, (d) provide a `\caption` statement, either at the top or bottom of the `figure` environment, and (e) end the `figure` environment.

---

*Update*, after the OP posted an MWE (minimum working example). The preceding suggestion applies to your case. The only addition is that I'd insert either `\medskip` or `\bigskip` between the end of the graph and the start of the `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{siunitx} % for '\si' macro
\usepackage{array}   % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped "look"
\centering
\caption{Some result} \label{fig.1}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=0.6\textheight]{my figure}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Channel No &1&2&3&4&5\\
\hline
Wavelength (\si{\micro\meter}) &7.43&11.03&12.02&12.66&14.08\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]